# Decision Tree: What do you do if all your classes have same frequency or you have no data points at the leaf node?

Tags: classification, cart

I was solving a question and I realized after splitting the tree on every attribute.

I reached a point where if my final attribute value is "No" then all the classes have equal frequency. if my final attribute value is "Yes" then I have no data points left.

I am confused about what to do in this situation. I couldn't find a definite answer.

Should I randomly pick any class or should I look at the frequency of classes in the parent node and pick the majority? That's all I could think of.

Comment: You shouldn't split a tree on every attribute in situations like this.  What software are you using? Which options did you use?  Did you prune your tree?

Comment: I am learning decision tree so I was manually solving the question myself. Just want to know how to handle such cases. Im aware about pruning.